# Ethereum Transaction for ERC20

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, erc-20, fees

If I want to airdrop the token to 10,000 addresses can we do it all under 1 transaction rather than 10,000 separate transactions all incurring separate fees.

Thanks
Amit M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of. If you do more work in a single transaction, that transaction will get more expensive (but cheaper than doing separate transactions).

That said, 10,000 transfers is too many. The required gas would exceed the current block limit, so such a transaction is impossible to get mined.

A more realistic number would be on the order of 100-1,000 transfers per transaction. Once you've written your code, it will be easy to measure the gas required and pick the right number.

Comment: Thanks @Smarx for the answer. You we can do 100-1000 transfers in single transaction?

Comment: I think you're missing a word in that question? As I said, I think 100-1,000 transfers in a single transaction is realistic.

Comment: A single transaction can do it but each token transfer is going to be a seperate internal transaction. The gas required for the token transfer is going to be the same. The gas saved will be a notable difference but not much I would say. It saves a lot of time though.

Comment: The gas saving will be quite significant. Each transaction has a base fee of 21,000, while an "internal transaction" (misleading term, really just a CALL opcode) has a base fee of around 700. (But see Appendix H of the yellow paper... calculating the gas cost of a CALL is tricky.) And, of course, if the airdrop code is part of the ERC20 token code, then there's no CALL at all.

Comment: I am still not sure, how in a single transaction we can do multiple transfers. I tried this to add a loop in method for 10 times. But in block explorer its showing 10 different mined transactions.

Comment: The loop needs to be in your Solidity code.

Comment: yes it was in solidity code only.

Comment: Well if you only sent one transaction, then that couldn't result in 10 different mined transactions. So either there weren't really 10 different mined transactions, or you had a loop somewhere that sent 10 different transactions. If you can share your code and your evidence for there being 10 different transactions mined, that would help.

Comment: This is method Which calls Transfer 10 Times
function transferto10Times(address to, uint256 value) returns (bool success){
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        transfer( to, value);
        
        return true;
    }

Comment: =====================================================================
This Method has been called 10 Times
===================================================================
function transfer(address to, uint256 value) returns (bool success){
        if(Balances[msg.sender]< _value) throw;
        if(Balances[_to] + _value < Balances[_to]) throw;
        //if(admin)

        Balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        Balances[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

Comment: So what's the problem? You said 10 transactions have been mined. Why do you believe that?

Comment: So you mean, my logic is correct, and its still a single transaction?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @smarx Thanks for the reply. Is there a way if i can save fees in airdrop. Like at the time of token creation if I can distribute the token among various addresses.